# How to get springSecurityService inside a grails utils package

Tags: spring, grails

Iam using spring-security-2.0 in my grails 2.4.4 application. I have created the following groovy class in my utils package.

```html
package com.util.portal;

import com.services.portal.UserSessionService
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;


public class CustomSessionControl implements HttpSessionListener {

 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent) {
  /* Do whatever we want */

 }

 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent) {
  /* Do whatever we want */
 }

}
```

I just want to use the springsecurityService inside the sessionCreated() method
to get the principle.

Actually my intention is setting all user details into the session when it create itself (from sessionCreated method).

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve `springSecurityService` from `Holders`.

On the top:

```
import grails.util.Holders
```

In the method:

```
def springSecurityService = Holders.applicationContext.springSecurityService
def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
```

Comment: I implemented your code like this def springSecurityService = Holders.applicationContext.springSecurityService;  String UserId = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getId(); and got an error like Message: Cannot invoke method getId() on null object

Comment: The good news is that `springSecurityService` is injected. And what do you need principal for?

Comment: I just need the id of the logged in user. This would get from the principal

Comment: In the controller I got the user id from springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getId(); but here it is not getting

Comment: Still same Cannot get property 'id' on null object

Comment: sessionCreated() of an HttpSessionListener is calling at the time of session creation. So I have a doubt that does the springSecurityService had have the user details at this time? I think that is why the null exception is happening.

Comment: I tried this code many times in my project. And yes, if the user is not logged in - so `currentUser` will return `null`. Login first.

Comment: What you mean by Login first.? In spring-security a session will only create after a successful login right?. My above class will call only after the successful authentication.  So there is no such scenario without the login. And my doubt is does my above HttpSessionListener class is calling before the springSecurityService get the current user details.